# Solana create_candy_machine result in custom program error: 0x8f

Tags: solana, metaplex, candy-machine

After uploaded my asset, I'm trying to create candy machine with

```
ts-node src/candy-machine-cli.ts create_candy_machine --env devnet --keypair "~\.config\solana\devnet.json" -s xxx -p 1
```

But I ran into

> Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom
> program error: 0x8f
> Program cndyAnrLdpjq1Ssp1z8xxDsB8dxe7u4HL5Nxi2K5WXZ invoke [1]
> Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]
> Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success
> Program log: Custom program error: 0x8f
> Program cndyAnrLdpjq1Ssp1z8xxDsB8dxe7u4HL5Nxi2K5WXZ consumed 17076 of 200000 compute units
> Program cndyAnrLdpjq1Ssp1z8xxDsB8dxe7u4HL5Nxi2K5WXZ failed: custom program error: 0x8f

The post on issue-exploer of metaplex talks about error: 0x8f doesn't seem to match my case.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in param `-s xxx`, the `xxx` should be the wallet public-key but I pasted candy-machine init public-key.